# AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager doesn't decrement since table cell recycling cancels image request

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm using `UIImageView+AFNetworking:setImageWithURLRequest` to load images into table view cells. It's working great and I tried using `AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager` as in the example below to display the activity indicator while the images are loading.

```c
[[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] incrementActivityCount]; 
[imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:placeholder]
  success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] decrementActivityCount];
  } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] decrementActivityCount];
  }
];
```

The problem I've run into is when scrolling quickly through the table view AFNetworking cancels certain requests and the `AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager` never gets decremented. Canceling requests does keep things fast and appears to be by design:

> "As table view cells are recycled, for instance, setting a new image URL will automatically cancel the previous request." https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Introduction-to-AFNetworking

Is there a way to detect the cancellation so I can decrement the `AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager` or is there a better way to make sure the requests and activity indicator stay in sync?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do this all you need to do is call:

```
AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.sharedManager.enabled = YES;
```

in you AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and then AFNetworking looks after hiding and showing the indicator as and when network connections start and stop.

Comment: Crazy. I could swear that when I initially built this that only having that didn't do the trick. Working like you mentioned now. Thanks.